# Searching and Modifying CSV File by row, just one or two element and not necessarily all elements in that row

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, csv, python-requests

### The problem

I want to know the correct algorithm/way on searching and modifying a certain element of my 2D list. The modified 2D list will be written later to csv file. Below is my script:

### Code

```
import csv
search = input("Enter name to find: ")
replace = input("Enter name replacement: ")
pendingFile = csv.reader(open("pendingLists.csv", "r"), delimiter=",")        
#Problem 1 -> Searching and Modifying algorithm here...  
#Problem 2 -> Writing Algorithm here where the row is modified...
```

### Expected Output

```
>>>Enter name to find: Mark
>>>Enter name replacement: Jave

Old listfile
~listFile.csv
Job,PB01
Mark,NU01
Jumeirah,SC01

Same modified listfile
~listFile.csv
Job,PB01
Jave,NU01
Jumeirah,SC01
```

Proposed searching algorithm that I found on web but still lacks on modifying to be synthesized on my code

```
for row in pendingFile:
    if search == row[0]:
        print(row)
```

I am still new and I have already surfed google and youtube for 2 days but not enough breakthroughs with this problem.
I really need help, I am a student and we're tasked to create GUI POS Python 3 Tkinter as final project individual.

My current programming problem may be big for me, but I genuinely Thank the generous help that you may offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I managed to construct of what I am looking for:

```
def dataRead():
    with open("Inventory_List.csv", "r") as my_csv:
        myFile = csv.reader(my_csv, delimiter=",")

        global dataInventoryList
        dataInventoryList = [[col[0], col[1], col[2], col[3], col[4], eval(col[5])] for col in myFile]


def dataWrite():
    with open("Inventory_List.csv", "w+") as my_csv:
        myFile = csv.writer(my_csv, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
        myFile.writerows(dataInventoryList)

def main():
    while True:
        found = False
        dataRead()
        print("==========================================================================")
        print("Before update;")

        for i in range(len(dataInventoryList)):
            for j in range(6):
                print(str(dataInventoryList[i][j]) + "\t", end="")
            print("")

        search = input("Enter product code: ")
        quantity = int(input("Please enter quantity: "))
        choice = int(input("Add stocks[1] Pull Stacks[2]\nChoice: "))

        for i in range(len(dataInventoryList)):
            if search == dataInventoryList[i][0]:
                found = True
                if choice == 1:
                    dataInventoryList[i][5] += quantity
                    break
                elif choice == 2:
                    if dataInventoryList[i][5] == 0:
                        print("Requested order is out of stocks!\n")
                        break
                    elif quantity > dataInventoryList[i][5]:
                        print("Requested order is out of range!\n")
                        break
                    elif quantity <= dataInventoryList[i][5]:
                        dataInventoryList[i][5] -= quantity
                        break

        if found == False:
            print("Requested order was not found on the database!\n")

        elif found == True:
            dataWrite()

        print("After update;")
        for i in range(len(dataInventoryList)):
            for j in range(6):
                print(str(dataInventoryList[i][j]) + "\t", end="")
            print("")

main()
```

Comment: Solved!
for col in my_csv:
         dataInventoryList.append([col[0], col[1]])

Answer (score 0):

The three-line fragment you posted is correct.
You may find it more convenient to use a dictionary reader: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader.
Then having read the file you wind up with a list of `dict`s in memory, and rather than a cryptic `0` you can use a symbolic column name for each access, as shown below.

```
for row in rows:
    if search == row['name']:
        print(f'Found {search}, converting to capitals.')
        row['name'] = search.upper()
```

Having made several such changes, you would likely want to save the updated rows, using a DictWriter.